# Parsing Really Messy Nested JSON Strings

Tags: pyspark

I have a series of deeply nested json strings in a pyspark dataframe column. I need to explode and filter based on the contents of these strings and would like to add them as columns. I've tried defining the StructTypes but each time it continues to return an empty DF.

Tried using json_tuples to parse but there are no common keys to rejoin the dataframes and the row numbers dont match up? I think it might have to do with some null fields

The sub field can be nullable

Sample JSON

```java
{
  "TIME": "datatime",
  "SID": "yjhrtr",
  "ID": {
    "Source": "Person",
    "AuthIFO": {
      "Prov": "Abc",
      "IOI": "123",
      "DETAILS": {
        "Id": "12345",
        "SId": "ABCDE"
      }
    }
  },
  "Content": {
    "User1": "AB878A",
    "UserInfo": "False",
    "D": "ghgf64G",
    "T": "yjuyjtyfrZ6",
    "Tname": "WE ARE THE WORLD",
    "ST": null,
    "TID": "BPV 1431: 1",
    "src": "test",
    "OT": "test2",
    "OA": "test3",
    "OP": "test34
  },
  "Test": false
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you edit your question to make it more clear what is being asked? Describe clearly what you are asking and then show us what you have tried including code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information.

Comment: We can't tell what is wrong with your code without seeing your code.